# Second wtform SelectField prevents code from running

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

On my website I'm designing I'm using flask and wtforms and it seems to be working just fine. I have the following code

```
class LoadDataForm(FlaskForm):
selectData = SelectField('Label 1:',choices=toy_data_lst)
#selectPredict = SelectField('Label 2:',choices=[('a','aaa')])
submit = SubmitField('Select')
```

However, when I remove the comment for that second SelectField creation, the code doesn't run. It doesn't stop or break the code or even give an error. In fact, the only response I get is from the console

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2020 09:56:35] "←[37mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2020 09:56:39] "←[37mPOST / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

I'm sure it's just some type of Syntax error or I'm forgetting something incredibly dumb but this is driving me insane.

entire flask file if it helps

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,session, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField
import toy_data

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

toy_data_lst = toy_data.get_choice()

class LoadDataForm(FlaskForm):
    selectData = SelectField('Label 1:',choices=toy_data_lst)
    selectPredict = SelectField('Label 2:',choices=[('a','aaa')])
    submit = SubmitField('Select')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():

    form = LoadDataForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dataset = toy_data.get_dataset(int(form.selectData.data))
        #form.selectPredict.choices = [('a','aaa')]
        return render_template('loadedData.html', form=form, dataset=dataset)

    return render_template('noData.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Which page is returned after the `POST` request? If it's `noData.html` then you know that the form doesn't pass `validate_on_submit()`.

Comment: It didn't load anything, so yea, it's not passing its validation but I cannot understand why. I ended up making a second class anyways but I don't get why that select file caused it to fail